# Intersection of subsets of $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on a countable set $\Omega$.For some $\omega\in\Omega$ define

$$S(\omega)=\bigcap\{B\in\mathscr{F}:\omega\in B\} $$

Is $S(\omega)\in \mathscr{F}$?

Comment: Hint:  The $\sigma$-algebra is closed under countable intersections (by applying De Morgan's laws).

Comment: Sure. But whether we deal with countable intersections? (I'm missing this part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to turn this intersection into a countable intersection. Write $\Omega$ as $\omega_n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$.

Now consider $\{B\in\mathscr F\mid\omega\in B\}$, let $B_n$ be some set in the collection such that $\omega_n\notin B_n$, if such set exists, otherwise take $\Omega$. Now show that $S(\omega)=\bigcap B_n$.